# WordPress registration message

Tags: login, user-registration

I manually approve user registrations on my WordPress site. My problem is I want to edit the message they see when they register on my site:

[image: WordPress Registration Message]

The problem is, I can't find where to edit that message. Tried looking at `wp-login.php` and `wp-signup.php` but can't find the code which consists of that message. Can someone tell me where I can edit it?

Comment: Are you using a membership plugin?

Answer (score 5):

This message is not part of the WordPress core. I confirmed this suspicion by searching for the message within the WordPress core files. When it was not found, I then searched the message using a search engine. It appears that you are using the [New User Approve Message plugin](https://github.com/picklewagon/new-user-approve).

This message is defined in [`new-user-approve/includes/messages.php#L33`](https://github.com/picklewagon/new-user-approve/blob/master/includes/messages.php#L33)

```
/**
 * The default message that will be shown to the user after registration has completed.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function nua_default_registration_complete_message() {
    $message = sprintf( __( 'An email has been sent to the site administrator. The administrator will review the information that has been submitted and either approve or deny your request.', 'new-user-approve' ) );
    $message .= ' ';
    $message .= sprintf( __( 'You will receive an email with instructions on what you will need to do next. Thanks for your patience.', 'new-user-approve' ) );
    $message = apply_filters( 'new_user_approve_pending_message_default', $message );
    return $message;
}
```

You can modify this message using the filter `new_user_approve_pending_message_default`.

```
add_filter( 'new_user_approve_pending_message_default',
            'wpse_new_user_approve_pending_message_default' );
function wpse_new_user_approve_pending_message_default( $message ) {
    // Customize $new_message as needed and return it.
    $new_message = sprintf( __( 'New message...', 'text-domain' ) );

    return $new_message;
}
```